# Chunk file upload not working

Tags: java, grails, groovy

We are trying to upload large files(more than 6gb) through jQuery fileupload and in grails we accessing the file as MultipartFile. When trying to write the same into byte array, getting "out of memory"("Caused by OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space") exception.Code snippet.

```
        def finalName =new File("${path}/${newFile}")
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(finalName ,true));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue without adding static heap size value in buildConfig.groovy file.

Thank you.

Comment: unsure what it has to do with buildConfig. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: Can you try `Files.move(file, finalName, REPLACE_EXISTING);` ?

Comment: @vahid : We tried to increase heap size by adding grails.project.fork.compile.jvmArgs=['-Xss1024m'] line.

Comment: @RandallFlagg : I tried the same. getting error. "Groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.nio.file.Files.move() is applicable for argument types: (org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile, java.io.File, java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption) values: [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@24870838, ...]
Possible solutions: move(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.Path, [Ljava.nio.file.CopyOption;), wait(), grep(), find(), any(), every()"

Comment: @SüreshAK and are you running the app within grails development or is on tomcat ? I hope you can start seeing gaps in your question.

Comment: @vahid : Inside grails development environment.